# Auditing or Rowcount for each DML Operation in Snowflake Stored Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dml, rowcount

I want to capture the auditing inside the stored procedure for the merge and insert statements and i have tried using Result_Scan by getting Query ID from the QUERY_HISTORY by session. But these statements are not allowed in the JavaScript procedure. Then i have created a function for getting Query ID for the latest executed SQL queries.

```
create or replace function GET_QUERY_ID()
   RETURNS VARCHAR
   AS 'SELECT QUID FROM (SELECT (QUERY_ID)::VARCHAR AS QUID FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION(CURRENT_SESSION()::NUMBER)) WHERE QUERY_TYPE IN (''INSERT'',''MERGE'') ORDER BY END_TIME DESC ) LIMIT 1';
```

And tried for creating another function for row count

```
create or replace function GET_RESULT_SCAN(P_QUERY_ID VARCHAR)
   RETURNS TABLE ( INSERT_ROWS NUMBER ,UPDATED_ROWS NUMBER)
   AS 'select * from (select "number of rows updated"::NUMBER as INSERT_ROWS, "number of multi-joined rows updated"::NUMBER as UPDATED_ROWS from table(result_scan(P_QUERY_ID)))';
```

But this is not working and these functions i can't call in the stored procedure created with JavaScript.
Kindly let me know the best practice to capture the auditing on the number of rows inserted and updated in stored procedure. Assume in a stored procedure there are 5-10 SQL statements.

Comment: Please [format your code correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), and use some line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple procedure that does a merge and captures & returns the number of rows insert and rows update:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE utl.arch_merge_sp(P_STAGE_TBL VARCHAR, P_FINAL_TBL VARCHAR)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS $$
  var sqlCmd = "";
  var sqlStmt = "";
  var result = "";

  try {
    sqlCmd = `
      MERGE INTO final_t F USING stage_t S
      ON F.KEY_ID = S.KEY_ID
      WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
       F.ATTR_NM = S.ATTR_NM
      ,F.ATTR_NBR = S.ATTR_NBR
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
       F.KEY_ID
      ,F.ATTR_NM
      ,F.ATTR_NBR
      ) VALUES (
       S.KEY_ID
      ,S.ATTR_NM
      ,S.ATTR_NBR);
      `;
    sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sqlCmd} );
    rs = sqlStmt.execute();

    sqlCmd = 
      `SELECT "number of rows inserted", "number of rows updated"
        FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))`;
    sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sqlCmd} );
    rs = sqlStmt.execute();
    rs.next();

    result += "Rows inserted: " + rs.getColumnValue(1) + ", Rows updated: " + rs.getColumnValue(2)

  }
  catch (err) {
    result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + " | State: " + err.state;
    result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
    result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
    }

  return result;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why just not use snowflake's [Statement](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#getNumRowsInserted) object methods?

You could also create a wrapper stored procedure, so you don't have to deal with the boilerplate code all of the time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXEC_SQL_SCRIPT (SQL_SCRIPT VARCHAR, STATEMENT_SEPARATOR VARCHAR) 
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$

var execReport = { status: "Succeeded",
                   statements : [] 
}

var stmtSep = ";"
if (STATEMENT_SEPARATOR != null) {
    stmtSep = STATEMENT_SEPARATOR;
}

var stmts = SQL_SCRIPT.split(stmtSep);

for (var i = 0; i < stmts.length; i++) {
    var stmtText = stmts[i].trim();
    
    if (stmtText.length > 0) {
        try {
            var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText : stmtText } );
            var rs = stmt.execute();

            execReport["statements"].push({ statement_no: i + 1, 
                                            status: "Succeeded",
                                            rowCount: stmt.getRowCount(),
                                            numRowsAffected: stmt.getNumRowsAffected(),
                                            numRowsDeleted: stmt.getNumRowsDeleted(),
                                            numRowsInserted: stmt.getNumRowsInserted(),
                                            numRowsUpdated: stmt.getNumRowsUpdated(),
                                            queryId : stmt.getQueryId(),
                                            sqlText: stmt.getSqlText(),
                                            error: null
                                        });
        } catch (err)  {
            var error = { code : err.code,
                          state : err.state,
                          message : err.message,
                          stackTraceTxt : err.stackTraceTxt
            };

            execReport["statements"].push({ statement_no: i + 1, 
                                            status: "Failed",
                                            rowCount: null,
                                            numRowsAffected: null,
                                            numRowsDeleted: null,
                                            numRowsInserted: null,
                                            numRowsUpdated: null,
                                            queryId : stmt.getQueryId(),
                                            sqlText: stmt.getSqlText(),
                                            error: error
                                        });

            execReport["status"] = "Failed";

            return execReport;  
        } 
    }
}

return execReport;

$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line **execute as caller** in the top of the stored procedure definition
:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] PROCEDURE <name> ( [ <arg_name> <arg_data_type> ] [ , ... ] )
  RETURNS <result_data_type> [ NOT NULL ]
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  [ { CALLED ON NULL INPUT | { RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT | STRICT } } ]
  [ VOLATILE | IMMUTABLE ]
  [ COMMENT = '<string_literal>' ]
  [ EXECUTE AS { CALLER | OWNER } ]
  AS '<procedure_definition>'
```